# raint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^(\*\.)?(((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm trying to deploy aws cdk app and I get this message :

"raint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: ^(*.)?(((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{0,62}[A-Za-z0-9]).)+((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,62}[A-Za-z0-9])$ (RequestId: ff57e645-81f1)"

What is **raint** ? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Is that a part of `xxx failed to satisfy constraint:`?

Comment: No. It's not a part of anything. It is on it's own like that. Just one line.

Comment: Fair to say "raint" is a truncated "constraint". Why you're not seeing or receiving the full message I don't know. Just find the place where that regex is defined, then you'll know what it refers to.